# Meteor: how to access another user's details?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

`Meteor.users.findOne()` gives me back my user document.

`Meteor.users.findOne({_id: 'my ID'})` gives me back my user document.

`Meteor.users.findOne({_id: 'another users's ID'})` gives me back UNDEFINED.

This is obviously restricted by security. But how can I access another users's account details e.g. _id, name, profile, etc?

Comment: did you publish the user with that particular ID ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add a publisher for the user. Here's an example:

```js
// The user fields we are willing to publish.
const USER_FIELDS = {
  username: 1,
  emails: 1,
};

Meteor.publish('singleUser', function (userId) {
  // Make sure userId is a string.
  check(userId, String);

  // Publish a single user - make sure only allowed fields are sent.
  return Meteor.users.find(userId, { fields: USER_FIELDS });
});
```

Then on the client you can [subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe) like this:

```js
Metor.subscribe('singleUser', userId);
```

or use a [template subscription](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe) like this:

```js
this.subscribe('singleUser', userId);
```

---

Security notes:

1. Always `check` the arguments to your publishers, or clients can do bad things like pass `{}` for `userId`. If you get an error, make sure you `meteor add check`.
2. Always use a `fields` option with the users collection. Otherwise you'll publish all of their secrets. See the "Published Secrets" section of [common mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes).

Comment: awesome for the check package. I just know that from the documentation

Comment: Thanks! I have the publisher but will check tonight.

Comment: How do I refer to the published user profile in the template? Do I still need a template helper?

Comment: You'd do a regular `find` or `findOne` like `Meteor.users.findOne(someUserId)`. Yes, you'd probably expose this to the template via a helper.

Answer (score 2):

Run it on the server like so:

Server:

```
Meteor.publish("otherUsers", function (userID) {
  return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userID});
});
```

Client:

```
Meteor.subscribe("otherUsers", <userIdYouWantToGetDetailsFor>);
```

Then you can just do a Meteor.users.findOne on the client **keep in mind you can only do it for your user and the userID that you passed in the meteor subscribe**

Comment: Thanks! I have the publisher but will check tonight.